# Number of labelled triangular cactus graphs

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, recurrence-relations

I want to count triangular cactus graphs: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cactus_graph#Triangular_cactus

I belive it can be done by creating recurrence realation, and then by analyzing its generating function, but I'm stuck finding it. It should be something like $a_n = \frac{n-2}{2}a_{n-2}$ (connecting two vertices to one, which is already added, to form a triangle, but their order doesn't matter). But this formula give wrong results.

Comment: Not sure if it's helpful for your case. But if everything is unlabeled, then the number of triangular cactus graphs of order $2n+1$ exactly the same as the number of trees of order $n$ I think (each vertex of the tree represents a triangle, with an edge indicating the triangles have a common vertex).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let
\begin{align}
T_n&=\text{# triangular cactus graphs with $n$ vertices}\\
R_n&=\text{# rooted triangular cactus graphs with $n$ vertices}
\end{align}
A rooted graph is a just a graph with one vertex singled out as the root, so $R_n=nT_n$. We introduce $R_n$ since it is more amenable to exponential generating function analysis.

Let $R(x)=\sum_{n\ge 1}R_n \frac{x^n}{n!}$ be the exponential generating function for $(R_n)_{n\ge 0}$. I claim that
$$
R(x)=x\left(1+\frac{R(x)^2}{2^1\cdot 1!}+\frac{R(x)^4}{2^2\cdot 2!}+\frac{R(x)^6}{2^3\cdot 3!}+\dots\right)=x\sum_{k \ge 0}(2k-1)!!\frac{R(x)^{2k}}{(2k)!}\tag1
$$
This is because choosing a rooted, triangular cactus graph is equivalent to:

- choosing a root, $v$,
- choosing a degree for the root, call it $2k$,
- partitioning the remaining vertices into $2k$ parts, and turning each part into a rooted triangular cactus graph (note that deleting the root $v$, together with all triangles touching $v$, leaves a disjoint union of $2k$ triangular cacti),
- choosing a perfect matching on these $2k$ smaller graphs. If two graphs with roots $w$ and $u$ are joined in the matching, the interpretation is the $\{v,w,u\}$ is a triangle in the whole graph, so this matching describes how the smaller graphs are joined together. Note that there are $(2k-1)!!=(2k-1)\cdot(2k-3)\cdots 3\cdots 1$ perfect matchings on a set of size $2k$, and the appearance of $(2k-1)!!$ in $(1)$.

This combinatorial relationship between $R_n$ and itself, when translated into an exponential generating function equation, results in exactly $(1)$. This equation can be written more simply as
$$
R(x)=x\exp(\tfrac12 R(x)^2)
$$
To extract $R_n$ from this generating function equation, you can use Lagrange inversion. Specifically, if we re-arrange this like
$$
R(x)\exp(-\tfrac12 R(x)^2)=x,\tag2
$$
then letting $$S(y)=y\exp(-\tfrac12 y^2/2),$$ we see that $(2)$ implies $R$ and $S$ are compositional inverses to each other, with $R(0)=S(0)=0$. The Lagrange inversion formula then states that
$$
R_n=[x^n]R(x)=\frac1n [x^{-1}]S(x)^{-n}.
$$
If you plug in the definition of $S(x)$, and do the algebra, the result is
$$
R_n=n^{(n-1)/2}\cdot (n-2)!!,
$$
which implies $$T_n=\tfrac1nR_n=n^{(n-3)/2}(n-2)!!$$ This formula is confirmed by the OEIS sequence for triangular cacti graphs: https://oeis.org/A034941.